# pop-to-buffer: Wrong type argument: window-valid-p, #<window 117>PNG warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

Tags: window, debugging, projectile

I occasionally run into the following error when opening a new file with projectile:

```
pop-to-buffer: Wrong type argument: window-valid-p, #<window 117>PNG warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
```

Which closes the entire frame.

How could I go about debugging this - or is this kind of error not really feasible? I'm not able to reproduce it, it happens randomly.

---

And again: `pop-to-buffer: Wrong type argument: window-valid-p, #<window 47>`

Comment: Try `(setq debug-on-error '(wrong-type-argument))`, when it happens again you should then get a backtrace which might give some more hints.